# Explanation of template boilerplate in onCreate

Tags: java, android

I wanna know how the code works and especially why super.onCreate( ) along with our own code is kept inside onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ }?

```java
public class myActivity extends Activity {
     @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.main);
     }
}
```

Comment: You should learn Java before Android, I suppose..?!!

Comment: Oh, just ignore it. It's android-related junk everybody just copy-pastes when they create a method. Back in the day google devs were not skilled enough to make it work without this garbage code. And now they just cant remove it because everyone got used to it.

Comment: read the docs and search you will find a bunch of answers.

Comment: @HirasawaYui I assume you are joking right? None of your statements are correct, every line has a purpose. `onCreate` is part of Android lifecycle. Without `Bundle` you will not be able to pass data between activities or to the current activity and `setContentView` sets a particular view layout for the current activity. Google never  changed it because there is nothing to change.

Comment: Yeah, I was just being sarcastic. Anyway, they could have added an empty version of `onCreate` method (like `void main()` in cpp)

Answer (score 3):

You're asking some questions that delve into some pretty fundamental aspects of Android.

### Lifecycle

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

This is one of the lifecycle methods for the Android component named Activity. There a bunch of these which all get called at different times. [Here is more information](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#oncreate) about Activity lifecycles.

### super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

This method calls the super class' `onCreate` method (the class you're `extend`ing from; `myActivity extends Activity`). It is expected, especially in an Android component, to call the super classes method. If you had overridden a custom `Activity` base class then this may contain some useful configuration and save you from coding it everywhere you wanted it.

### savedInstanceState

The `savedInstanceState` that's passed is a way of saving information across `Acivity` restarts. An `Activity` can be restarted due to a configuration change, switching from portrait to landscape, for example.

This `Bundle` contains information that you, the developer save away in the following inherited method.

```java
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

[Here are the docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states#onsaveinstancestate) on that

### setContentView

This sets the layout that should be inflated and displayed for the `Activity`. An `Activity` doesn't need to have a layout, but 99% of the time, they're used for UI stuff

Answer (score 0):

In android Activity means a Screen. The method onCreate() will be called immediately  when The Activity of your app will be created and drawn on screen. This method needs to be overridden because this class inherits from Activity class which also has an onCreate method. The method onCreate uses Bundle in its parameter list, which is actually a bundle of views (ex : Button, Imageview, etc).
The method setContentView() is used to set a layout which holds UI components of your activity written in xml. The layout file can be fetched using R.java file which automatically stores them, that is why it has been called like this : setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);